# laravel - post function not working through db

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
    <!-- Page Header -->
    <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('{{asset('assets/img/home-bg.jpg')}}')">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <div class="site-heading">
              <h1>Laravel Blog</h1>
              <span class="subheading">The php framework for web artisans</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          @foreach($posts as $post)
          <div class="post-preview">
            <a href="#">
              <h2 class="post-title">
                {{$post->title}}
              </h2>
            </a>
            <p class="post-meta">Posted by
              <a href="#">{{$post->user->name}}</a>
              on {{$post->created_at}}</p>
          </div>
          <hr>
          @endforeach

          <!-- Pager -->
          <div class="clearfix">
            <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="#">Older Posts </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

controller code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PublicController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      $posts= Post::all();
      return view('welcome', compact( 'posts'));
    }
    public function singlePost($id){
      return view('singlePost');
    }
    public function about(){
      return view('about');
    }
    public function contact(){
      return view('contact');
    }
    public function contactPost(){

    }
}
```

I have been revising my code for more than 24 hours still cant figure out why the posts are not being displayed on my homepage. the routes are okay they are working correctly just the information when passing the posts are not being displayed could anyone assist pls

Comment: Show your controller code.

Comment: added in the post

Comment: Please edit your question with the controller code rather than commenting it.

Comment: Have you try to `dd($posts)` in your controller?

Comment: Check your database if you have any data for posts.

Comment: instead of compact('posts')?

Comment: Code seems to be fine. after `$posts = Post::all();` write `dd($posts);` and check the output.

Comment: i got a 500 error (internal server error) adfter dd($posts);

Comment: 500 error usually comes with a log entry and an error message. What does that message say?